# Estaba creando mi app con xamarin y me aparece este error antes no me aparecia y todo es con la misma etiqueta ADB0010

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

[image: Este es el mensaje constantemente que me aparece cuando estoy compilando mi aplicacion y esto sucedio de un momento a otro ya que no me estaba apareciendo nunca y no me sale ningun error de codigo dentro de este por lo cual me parece muy raro]

Este es el mensaje constantemente que me aparece cuando estoy compilando mi aplicacion y esto sucedio de un momento a otro ya que no me estaba apareciendo nunca y no me sale ningun error de codigo dentro de este por lo cual me parece muy raro

Comment: no foto pone el error en texto por favor

Comment: parece un error de emulador. Elimine el emulador y vuelvalo a crear y asegurese que tenga el sdk de la version de android instalado

Answer (score 0):

Creo que hay problemas con el emulador o algún conflicto a la hora de ejecutarse

Intenta corregirlo de forma manual en el archivo .csproj creando una aplicación en blanco y observando si el error persiste

El primer paso es verificar es que si crear una nueva aplicación en blanco, funciona.

Tiene que ver con un problema de version en algun Nuget, o en la version de Xamarin.Forms.